# How to list clients that have used your wifi hotspot on a Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, wifi-hotspot

Is there a way to list clients currently using my mobile hotspot? Or even better does it log info on the clients that connect?

I have some totally unexplained bandwidth usage when I had it on and took a 5 hour nap, while the password wasn't that weak, I'd like to check to make sure no one besides me was using it.

Edit: Preferably without root. Although, I might root it if it means I can actually LOG the activity.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted, you can open the file located at /data/misc/dhcp/dnsmasq.leases with an editor. There you can see information about connected devices.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996351/wi-fi-tethering-how-to-get-list-of-connected-clients

(This I maybe duplicate of the link provided)

Comment: See my edit/update to the question.